# $_COOKIE not working when cookie set on subdomain - and read on same subdomain

Tags: php, cookies, set

I am currently setting a cookie on a PHP page of my subdomain

```
$asdasd = "1";
$expires = time() + 86400; // 1 day
if (($username == $actualusername) && ($password == $actualpassword))
{
    setcookie("loggedin",$asdasd, $expires);
    header('Location: exampleurl');
}
```

I am then trying to read it on another page on the SAME subdomain:

var_dump($_COOKIE['loggedin']);

nothing is returned - even though I can see the cookie set in the browser privacy settings.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Try to add the subdomain as 5th parameter to the setcookie-function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the issue must be around path where you set your cookie, in your case solution would be

```
setcookie("loggedin",$asdasd, $expires, "/");
```